# Laravel eloquent searching/filtering

Tags: php, laravel, filtering

I am implementing a filtering/searching feature for my film profile, i come from a symfony background and just learning laravel as i go along, i would have this query within a new repository e.g `FilmRepository` to keep the query seperate and the controller less cluttered

my first option was to create a join query in the repo which joins all of these tables together but what if i want it to filter/search even if a particular dropdown option isnt chosen? im abit lost on how to tackle this feature

this is the rough repo funtion i've created that needs more work

**Repository**

```
 public function searchFilms()
    {
        $films= Film::from('films')
            ->join('categories', 'films.id', '=', 'categories.film_id')
            ->join('locations', 'id', '=', 'location.id')
            ->join('age_rating', 'id', 'age_rating.id')
            ->orderBy('updated_at', 'desc');
    }
```

I know im going to need these filter options as query parameters how do i do this within laravel?

Can i get some help with how to tackle this solution? thanks

Comment: take  a look at this maybe it helps you 

https://laraveldaily.com/less-know-way-conditional-queries/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In laravel controller actions can receive a Request object as param that can be used to fetch the filters from your front-end.

```
public function searchFilms(Request $request)
{ 
    $data = $request->all();
    $user = Auth::user();

    return FilmResource::collection($this->repository->searchFilms($data));
}
```

the Request class has more than one way of getting its data, you can read [this](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/requests#retrieving-input) to learn about them, but, ->all()(more about it [here](https://laravel.com/api/5.6/Illuminate/Http/Request.html#method_all) is one of the ways.

Then pass the data to your searchFilms function and apply the filters

```
 public function searchFilms($filters)
 {
        $films= Film::from('films')
            ->join('categories', 'films.id', '=', $filters['film_id'])
            ->join('locations', 'id', '=', $filters['location_id'])
            ->join('age_rating', 'id', $filters['age_rating_id'])
            ->orderBy('updated_at', 'desc');
 }
```

Something like that would work, I do not know the name of your inputs but you could get an idea from this.

**Edited**

So  in order to clarify your question in the comments.

$request->all() will return an array of your posted data in which the attribute name of your inputs will be the key for each value. So for instance, let's say I have the following html form:

```
<form>
 <input name="name" type="text" value="john doe" />
 <input name="age" type="text" value="39" />
</form>
```

`$request->all()` would be an array like this `['title' => 'john doe', 'age' => '39']`;

Comment: by inputs are you referring to the dropdown options you can choose from? if so ill edit my question with them so you could adjust your answer im unsure on what i should be writing for the $filters

Comment: Yup, I was referring to the dropdowns.

Comment: oh yeah i understand how the $request->all() works, what i am referring too is what data would replace $filters from the question data i gave above

Comment: well the data that you pass to your function... in my answer I passed the $request->all()

Comment: if the answer was helpful for you please take a time to mark as right or to up arrow it ^^

Comment: Apologies for the faraway question but how does 'Film::from' work I have not seen this eloquent command?